# Getting the last inserted row after doing an INSERT in PDO (with MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

when inserting a new object (as a row) into the MySQL database I want to get the last inserted row back (id is NOT always enough, as I want to use this in a generic functions where some INSERTs do not have any auto-incremented IDs).

I need this to give the full object back on success with POSSIBLY database-created id, timestamp, or in some cases just the values I knew before inserting - so PDO::lastInsertId does not solve the problem.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (".$colinsert.") VALUES (".$colbind.")";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$ex = $stmt->execute();
// ... if $ex was successful, how do I retrieve the last inserted row now?
```

A database-independent solution would be nice, but if it is MySQL specific it is also ok :-)

Edit: To prevent some misunderstandings - e.g. I have the table user_contact_connection with the following rows (contact_id,user_id,additional_connection_info). The primary key is (contact_id,user_id). PDO::lastInsertId returns 0 in this case, as there is no auto increment column.

O.k. in this case I KNOW which row I have been inserting, however I still hope to find a way to just get the last inserted row generically WITHOUT explicitly querying for the IDs? Is this even possible?

Comment: You already have `$colbind` so what's the issue? Get the last insert id with `->lastInsertId` and query the database on that, giving you the full info for that row.

Comment: do you have primary key?

Comment: Sometimes I have a primary key with one col, sometimes a primary key with multiple cols - as already said, I need it for a generic function and I want the ROW returned.

Comment: With mysql you can have only 1 `auto_increment` id. This is what you get back with `lastInsertId`. If you have composite index then the other parts you have to provide manually anyway. Only unknown part is auto_incremaented value for which you have solution for.

Comment: Ah ok thank you I did not want to exclude the possibility of multiple auto_incremented sequences. This simplifies the problem and may also be a good answer (however it would be COMFORTABLE if they also would provide a function to get the full row).

Comment: I think this will probably never happen. Some ORM-s or libraries do populate the id for you automatically but behinde the scenes they do it same way. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object after persisting in the db and you want the object to have the values that your db calculates (eg. have the default values back that you don't provide with the insert statement, get the timestamps resulting from MySQL NOW(), etc.), probably the best is fetching after insert. However, using some ORM library like Doctrine, you could construct the object with all the values before persisting but then you have to provide defaults, timestamps, etc. (autoincrement must be fetched anyway).